# Ubuntu disables ssh login permanently after changing sshd_config

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

So I have been trying to follow this [guide](http://spenserj.com/blog/2013/07/15/securing-a-linux-server/) and so far I have wasted ~5 hours launching Ubuntu 14.04 instances to try different setup every time, the issue is basically quite common but non of the fixes I have found solve it.

I follow the guide up to modifying the sshd_config and adding my key that was generated from Putty, then as soon as I restart ssh service I keep getting the basic error "Server refused our key" when I have investigated this issue, I have found that this message keeps coming up in the logs over and over (No supported authentication methods available [preauth]).

What I have tried so far is changing permissions, creating ssh folder at home folder of the user.

Could you please help me spot the issue in guide I have linked.

Comment: Are you aware that you have to export your key in a special format in Putty to get it to work with OpenSSH?

Comment: yes I know I need a key in ppk format, and I know how to setup a profile to include the key every time i attempt to connect...

Comment: You've also added your public key to the server's `authorized_keys` file for the user you're logging in as, right? As in, `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: yep just like the guide states, I tried adding it couple of times in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and one time in the directory you've mentioned with correct user ofc

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the contents of sshd_config? Also check the server logs in /var/log for any relevant log entries for sshd.